# Failure when push_back a structure that contains a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have the following simplified code:

```
struct sMatch
{
   public:
      sMatch( ULONG size )
      {
         myVector.assign( size, false );
      }
      std::vector< bool > myVector;
}

std::vector< sMatch > myMatchVector;
sMatch temp( 3 );
myMatchVector.push_back( temp );
```

Periodically I am seeing a **signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN)** crash when it executes the push_back(). Backtrace points to **myVector** in the + operator, but it is unclear to me what is wrong with the implementation.

I have been trying different implementation/memory allocation for **myVector** within the sMatch constructor but none of my attempts have successfully prevented this crash.

Comment: Make a small reproducible example that shows the problem. There's nothing wrong with what you've posted so far.

Comment: Where is the + operator?

Comment: The problem was that I needed a copy constructor that copied each element individually:

      `sMatch( const sMatch & parent )`
      `{`
         `// This line causes crash I was seeing before`
         `// mMatches = parent.mMatches;`

         `// This fixes the problem`
         `for (int i = 0; i < parent.myVector.size(); i++)`
         `{`
            `myVector.push_back( parent.myVector.at( i ) );`
         `}`
      `}`

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what else is going on, it's hard to say, but I recently ran into a problem with dynamically allocated members of one class being written outside their bounds and overwriting the members of another class.

Which is to say, it seems possible that the address alignment error is because something else is overwriting your vector.

Again, a more complete example is probably the next step... unless you ARE getting that error with THIS example...

Comment: I've had this also, and seemingly preventing by using an explicit copy construture seemed to do the trick. I'd put this down to compiler issues, as it should fill one in on compilation automatically.